# What would happen if we took out the moon?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, earth

I've noticed when I look this up online with a quick Google search this theme emerges: that without the moon, if it were to disappear, the days would speed up a lot to say, 9 hours long and you will get strong winds--greater variability in weather.

The idea seems to be, just as we have this causality of the early solar system fast forwarding to eventual Earth-moon tidal force lockstep with its effect of 'Earth rotation braking', then it self-evidently follows that there's an opposing angular momentum release unto Earth from moon's sudden absence and subsequent shortening of the day over time from this, as opposed to continuation on trend itself following from the same source justification of angular momentum. Earth's own angular momentum of our rotation slowing.

The latter is more what I'm thinking.

24 hour days and sun tides, til over a very long time, 25, 26, 27 hour days et al.

Comment: Mars has no significant moon and similar length of day to Earth.

Comment: See also [Earthscience.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't think this question is in scope here, but looks like a good question for the proposed site [Scientific Imagination](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination)

Comment: It would mean we used [enough power](https://what-if.xkcd.com/13/).

Answer (score 5):

The moon saps rotational energy from Earth and converts it into an increasing distance from the Earth. Earth's day gets longer over time as a result.
Removing the moon altogether ends this. so the lengthening of Earth's day slows down.
The moon also stabilizes Earth's axis tilt, IIRC. Without this, you'll get more variation in axis tilt which has major impact on climate.